# How do I filter out addresses using HTTPS for a D-Link router?

Tags: router, https, parental-controls

I recently got a new router, a DRL-600L Router from D-Link, and was setting up some filters to block out certain websites.  One problem I am having is blocking out addresses that use `https` instead of `http`.

For example, I'm trying to block out Facebook, because Facebook.   So far, the filter filters `http://www.facebook.com` perfectly fine, but for the url `https://www.facebook.com`, it won't block that.

How can I block those kinds of websites?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can point your router to opendns.com and setup a free account and block anything you want.  Unfortunately Dlink does not give you an easy way to do this, hence going to opendns.com.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming it's a DIR-600L router, and that you're using the built-in parental control feature. If it doesn't work using https, then this router doesn't support filtering https based on domain name. This is more difficult to do, especially since some browsers do not send the domain name before establishing a secure connection, at which point the traffic is encrypted and the router can't filter anymore.

You can use the firewall to block Facebook's know IP addresses, though you should be aware that they may change at any time. If the router supports IPv6 and you have an IPv6 prefix assigned by your ISP, don't forget to filter Facebook's IPv6 addresses. A quick search will give you a list of IP addresses used by Facebook.

Answer (score 2):

I found an easier wasy of doing this using the Windows hosts file.

Open the hosts file in Notepad, from the location C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc
Add the following lines after the last line. **Do not add** http or https

```
127.0.0.1          www.facebook.com
```

Answer (score 1):

An https URL block is not supported except in some newer models in routers.
You can block these URLs using your `hosts` file.

Steps:

1. Open the `hosts` file in Notepad form the location `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc`
2. Add the following line after the last line

   ```
   127.0.0.1          www.facebook.com facebook.com
   ```

Result: It blocks the URL assuming the given address is from the local machine itself.

Comment: The `https://` or `http://` parts are wrong here.  The file contains a mapping from IP addresses to host names, not URLs. (Also, multiple hosts with the same IP address usually go on the same line.)

Comment: The host file should contains hostnames **not** urls.