# D-Link router website filter doesn't work for some websites

Tags: networking, router, dns

I'm trying to set up a whitelist on my DIR-810L router, and it's allowing some websites to pass through. Specifically, ones I often use. I've confirmed that the schedule is working properly because when I set it up to use a blacklist, some websites are blocked correctly while others aren't.

For example, the list contains facebook.com and netflix.com.

If I set the router to blacklist, I can't access netflix, but I can access facebook. (Though not links FROM facebook due to the wrapper facebook puts around them.)

If I set the router to whitelist, I can access netflix and facebook, but also reddit, while I can't access other websites I rarely use.

At this point, I'm almost certain there's some kind of caching going on, but I can't figure out what to do about it. Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried clearing the dns cache (ipconfig /flushdns)? Also, did the other sites utilize HTTPS? It could be the filtering doesn't handle HTTPS traffic well. As an alternative you could just force all DNS traffic to be redirected to OpenDNS, and [configure](http://superuser.com/questions/622182/how-do-i-filter-out-addresses-using-https-for-a-d-link-router) it to your heart content

Comment: 1. Manual whitelisting is impractical. Say you allow facebook, fine, it sorta works, But what about pictures that are on Akamai? and content that links eslewhere? Scripts? It breaks too much. 2 Its probably just intercepting DNS in the simplest form, if any users wanted to bypass it they'd just have to enter a new DNS address so its not going to be super effective.

Comment: I only want to allow a couple of websites where that shouldn't be an issue. This is for me personally, to disable things like reddit / facebook in the mornings when I need to get to work, but allow a couple of basic sites that I'd like to quickly check.